# left side division: transfering from matlab to scilab

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, least-squares, scilab

I'm trying to implement some filter fitting routines in Scilab which are already inherent to Matlab. I'm trying to compute filter coefficients through a least Squares algorithm as in invfreqz.m. To realize that I have to compute a left side matrix division on some nearly singular matrices. Problem is that Scilab yields different results from this calculation than matlab and I can't fix the problem. The code is the following:

```
matrix = [336.1810  331.8898  331.8898  336.1810  331.8898; 331.8898  336.1810  320.9743  331.8898  336.1810; 331.8898  320.9743  336.1810  331.8898  320.9743; 336.1810  331.8898  331.8898  336.1810  331.8898; 331.8898  336.1810  320.9743  331.8898  336.1810];
vector = [-331.8898; -320.9743; -336.1810; -331.8898;  -320.9743];
result = matrix \ vector;
```

Matlab gives me the result:

```
result =
 -0.5078
  0.5078
 -1.0000
  0.5078
 -0.5078
```

and Scilab yields:

```
result  =
  0.00000000000000050  
  0.                   
- 0.99999999999999856  
  0.                   
- 0.00000000000000219
```

Performing the calculation with both software gives me the warning:

```
> Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
```

with different rcond values

```
matlab: RCOND =  1.703907e-17
Scilab: rcond=   0.0000D+00
```

I checked Matlab's invfreq.m and they do it exactly the same way, but the results differ from Scilab. Even the warning shows as well. :) Now I need to obtain the same result in Scilab but I can't find a workaround because I have no clue what's going on. Anybody might have an idea or even a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The result is numerically unstable. You shouldn't put any stock in either answer.

Comment: If it helps, I tried the code on R2014A on a 64 bit windows machine and a 64 bit linux machine and got two different answers from the same code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. as said invfreqz.m the matlab signalprocessing function is using the exact same algorithm and gives me the exact same warning. means that the matlab inherent method produces unstable results aswell. i fitted a lot of filters with that method. :) Very confusing... I'm on Matlab R2015A btw..

Answer (score 1):

In case a future reader happens to get in the same situation: i composed a testing transfer function that accidentially resulted in a singular matrix, that can not be solved with certainty with the algorithm found in invfreqz.m. For those who are interested, the algorithm roots in a paper called "complex curve fitting" written by E.C. Levy

Answer (score 1):

If a problem is ill conditionned as yours, there is no numerical algorithm able to provide accurate results.

The error  on A\B operation can be estimated  by

```
 norm(B)*%eps*cond(A)
```